# Migrating Type Library File to C++Builder Rio 10.3.1

Tags: clang, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am working with C++Builder 10.3 Rio Update 1. I am having a problem migrating some Type Library files to the clang C++17 32bit compiler. I have an application created with the Classic Compiler (C++98) that uses a Type Library. I imported the Type Library years ago and created the three files `_OCX.dcr`, `_TLB.cpp`, `_TLB.h`.

When I try to compile this application in the clang C++17 compiler, I get the error:

> [bcc32c Error] ddfpbridge_TLB.h(304): enumerator value evaluates to 2147549182, which cannot be narrowed to type 'int'.

Each of the four lines inside the brackets below gives this same error. Can you suggest a code change to get it to compile?

```
// ***************************************************//
// Declaration of Enumerations defined in Type Library                    
// ***************************************************//

enum class HRESULTS
{
 HRESULTS_E_SERVERISNULLOREMPTY = 0x8000FFFE, 
 HRESULTS_E_USERNAMEISNULLOREMPTY = 0x8000FFFD, 
 HRESULTS_E_PASSWORDISNULLOREMPTY = 0x8000FFFC, 
 HRESULTS_E_SYMBOLISNULLOREMPTY = 0x8000FFFB 
};
```

I have tried to re-import the Type Library and recreate these files in the current version of C++Builder, but the import wizard gives the error message:

> Error accessing the OLE registry

Comment: What does line 304 in `ddfpbridge_TLB.h` actually look like? I suspect the error is not on the declaration of the enum values themselves but rather where the enum values are used elsewhere.

Comment: Line 304 is the first line inside the brackets: HRESULTS_E_SERVERISNULLOREMPTY = 0x8000FFFE,

Comment: `0x8000FFFE` is beyond the upper range for an `int` (`0x7FFFFFFF`). Clang is simply more strict about things like that than the classic Borland compiler was. You are going to have to use the negative decimal equivalents of the hex values, eg: `HRESULTS_E_SERVERISNULLOREMPTY = -2147418114`, 
 `HRESULTS_E_USERNAMEISNULLOREMPTY = -2147418115`, 
 `HRESULTS_E_PASSWORDISNULLOREMPTY = -2147418116`, 
 `HRESULTS_E_SYMBOLISNULLOREMPTY = -2147418117`, or else specify the underlying type of the enum to be an `unsigned int` instead of an `int`, eg: `enum class HRESULTS : std::uint32_t { ... }`